# setXXX methods of PreparedStatement not working

Tags: java, debugging, jdbc

I got something like this.

```
PreparedStatement statement = manager.getConnection().prepareStatement("delete from student_marks where reg_number = ? and semester = ?");      
statement.setInt(1,1);
statement.setString(2,"S1");    
System.out.println(statement.executeUpdate());
```

But the executeUpdate is returning 0 when I do this. If I directly replace the '?' with the values, then executeUpdate is woriking properly. In my case, it returned 4 meaning that 4 rows were deleted. I am not able to understand where the problem lies.

Comment: What are the column types of `reg_number` and `semester`?

Comment: have you reinserted the rows before testing? if you've deleted them once and try again, there's nothing to delete for the same parameters ;)

Comment: @beny23 reg_number is number and semester is varchar2

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your column type... If column type for reg_number is number(any numeric data type), then only you must set it integer, else otherwise you must set it using string.

```
PreparedStatement statement = manager.getConnection().prepareStatement("delete from student_marks where reg_number = ? and semester = ?");      
statement.setString(1,"1");
statement.setString(2,"S1");    
System.out.println(statement.executeUpdate());
```

As jlordo pointed out, Did you reinsert the records before deleting it next time?

Comment: Yes, the column type is number and I did reinsert before running the above code.